# Trouble with viewport for mobile in landscape and portrait

Tags: css, mobile, viewport

I have read a lot of ["viewport" tutorials](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/), but I just can't seem to find a simple solution that **always** displays a div centered and fully visible. I have created a [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C784W/), which works on desktop and on iPad in landscape mode. In portrait mode, and on smaller tablets, the div is not fully visible, even in landscape mode.

If I set the initial scale lower, then the div is also scaled down in landscape mode, where it now becomes too small on the iPad! What could be the correct viewport settings...?

**HTML**:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div id="appcontainer">
    <div id="main">Main content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
} 

#appcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%; top:50%;
  margin:-320px 0 0 -400px;
  width:800px; height:640px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  background-color: rgba(146,255,92,0.74);
  color:white;
}

#main {
  width:800px; height: 530px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to scale with the window and always be centered, use percentages, not fixed pixels.  It can be a pain to setup, but always works.

```
#appcontainer {
position: absolute;
left:50%; top:50%;
margin:-10% 0 0 -8%;
width:80%; height:auto;
border:1px solid blue;
background-color: rgba(146,255,92,0.74);
color:white;
}

#main {
width:100%; height: 100%;
border:1px solid red;
background-color: white;
color:black;
}
```

Comment: Additional reading would be CSS media queries: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/